# get object property on listview item press

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to android and my scenario is as follows:
I have a list view that is bound to an array list of type Department (a simple object with id and name properties). My goal is to have the list view display the department names (done by overriding the `toString()` method of the Department class) and when I click on a list view item, I want to pass the ID property of the selected item to another Activity. So, how do I get the ID property on item select?

Comment: without code we are not able to help you can you please update your code.

Comment: show at least your listview clicklistener and your adapter

Comment: You probably can't store data against list items. Most likely your item selection event will return the number of the item pressed. Use that number to collect the actual ID stored in an array (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

        }
    });
```

Here in onItemClick you will get the position of the selected item and you can get your id like this:

```
yourArrayList.get(position).getDepartmentId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) / [Set Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) in android for this purpose.

Following example will help :

- [setTag() and getTag() on ListView](http://blog.mettletech.co/wp/blog/settag-and-gettag-on-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

You can override onItemClick method and get the position of your view

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters

- parent   The AdapterView where the click happened.
- view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a
  view provided by the adapter)
- position The position of the view in the adapter.
- id   The row id of the item that was clicked.